# use python pandas to check if one dataframe contains records that don't exists in another by a set of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have 2 pandas dataframes df1 and df2, they are same columns: A,B,C,D
How can I check if df2 have records in column A,B that don't exists in df2 in columns A,B

Oracle sql equivalent would be:

```
   select A, B from df2 
   minus 
   select A, B from df1
```

Comment: No, not on the same rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will put only those records in 'final' df that exists only in df2

```
final=df1.merge(df2[['A','B']],on=['A','B'],how='right',indicator=True)
final=final.loc[final['_merge']=='right_only']
print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to subtract df1 from df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Sue']})

pd.concat([df1,df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

   A    B
3  4  Sue
```